# What does м ж.-д. stands for in the screenshot below？

Tags: узус, сокращения

What does the **м ж.-д.** stand for in the screenshot below? Source: [brks.info](https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«м», I suppose, is for the masculine gender (мужской род) of the word, and my guess is that «ж.-д.» stands for «Железнодорожный», something about railways.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)